# If the mean of a r.v. $Y$ conditional on $X=x, W=w$ is known, sampling $X,W$ and then averaging yields $Y$. How can we represent this formulaically?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose the mean of a r.v. $Y$ conditional on $X=x, W=w$ is known, such that,

$$
f(x,w) = E(Y\mid X=x, W=w)
$$

where $X,W,Y$ are all discrete random varaibles.

Then one way to find the marginal average of $Y$ is to randomly sample a $X=x$ and $W=w$ from their respective distributions. Then, we can record the value of $f(X=x,W=w)$ and then repeat the process. Averaging over many such $f(x,w)$ estimates the mean of $Y$. I am wondering how this is written formally in terms of iterated expectations.

My first intuition is that we can first average over the $X$'s, then the $W$'s, which leads to

\begin{align}
\sum_w\left(\sum_x E(Y\mid X=x, W=w)P(X=x)\right)P(W=w)
\end{align}

However, a second intuition is that in the process above, the random sampling of $X$ and $W$ occurred at the same time, so we might instead have:

\begin{align}
\sum_w\sum_x\sum_x E(Y\mid X=x, W=w)P(X=x, W=w)
\end{align}

which in general is **not** equal to the first expression, unless $X$ and $W$ were independent.

I did see that if we modified the first equation to be instead:

\begin{align}
\sum_w\left(\sum_x E(Y\mid X=x, W=w)P(X=x\mid W=w)\right)P(W=w)
\end{align}

then we have the 2nd equation. I am wondering which of these is correct. Would anyone have insights here? Thanks.

Comment: the last two equations are equivalent and correct

Comment: I agree with @angryavian and just wanna add that "sampling $(X,W)$ to find $E[Y]$" is an idea that works regardless of whether $X$ and $W$ are dependent or independent.  (E.g. imagine these r.v.s are weight, height and age of a random person.)  That's why you need the more general formulation, i.e. last two equations.

Comment: To add to @antkam's comment: the key is to sample from the *joint distribution* $(X,W)$. In your original post, you state "sample a $X=x$ and $W=w$ from their respective distributions" which is not correct [if I interpret that sentence as "sample from their respective *marginal* distributions"].